# how to make the typescript unit test handle the parameter with type

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a typescript function look like this:

```
export const AuthHandler = {
    isTokenNeedRefresh: (seconds: number) => {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(WheelGlobal.ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME);
        if(!accessToken){
            return false;
        }
        const claim = JSON.parse(atob(accessToken.split('.')[1]));
        const exp = claim.exp;
        const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        // seconds was the token prereload time gap
        const isExpired = exp < now + seconds;
        if (isExpired) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

now I am adding a unit test for this function, this is my unit test code looks like:

```
import 'mocha'
import { expect } from 'chai'
import AuthHandler from "../../../src/auth/extension/AuthHandler";

describe('Auth Test', function () {
    it('Parse jwt token', async function () {
        const result = AuthHandler.isTokenNeedRefresh(16000);
        expect(typeof result).to.be('boolean');
    })
})
```

when I run this unit test code, show error like this:

```
 FAIL  test/auth/extension/AuthHandler.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/src/auth/extension/AuthHandler.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (8:32)

       6 |
       7 | export const AuthHandler = {
    >  8 |     isTokenNeedRefresh: (seconds: number) => {
         |                                 ^
       9 |         const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(WheelGlobal.ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME);
      10 |         if(!accessToken){
      11 |             return false;

      at Parser._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:150:45)
      at Parser.raiseWithData (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:145:17)
      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:89:17)
      at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:174:16)
      at Parser.expect (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:150:28)
      at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1702:14)
      at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1122:21)
      at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:682:23)
      at Parser.parseUpdate (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:662:21)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:633:23)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.414 s
Ran all test suites within paths "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/test/auth/extension/AuthHandler.test.ts".
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? BTW, I run this test from visual studio code like this:

[image]

Comment: It looks like your loader isn’t transpling into JavaScript

Comment: What command did you use to run the test? Do you have a `.mocharc.json` file?

Comment: I run it on the visual studio code IDE.